# Can a fluorescent light fixture that uses T8 tubes contain both a shunted and non-shunted light base?

Tags: electrical, lighting, fluorescent

I used a multi-meter to check the lamp bases to see if they were shunted. Two of the four lamp bases showed they were shunted and the another two lamp bases showed they were non-shunted.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe ask about that instead of abstract theory.

Comment: I check the lamp bases after they were disconnected from the electronic ballast. The probes of the multi-meter were actually placed on the contacts in lamp bases. I did this to avoid any kind of resistance. I am checking to the lamp bases because I want to remove the ballast and Install T8 direct wire Led Tub lights. The Manufacturer of the LED T8 Tubes states in installation Guide "**Ensure the lamp holders are SHUNTED for Double Ended T8 applications."**

Answer (score 1):

On *instant-start* ballasts, or on double-ended LEDs, being shunted or not does not matter.

However a resistance test isn¡t necessarily the final word on the subject. The powered-down ballast may have quite low resistance between the terminals.